# Linux AMD-FX 8350 temperature monitoring

Tags: linux, temperature, debian-squeeze, lm-sensors

I’m trying to get the CPU temperature for my AMD-FX8350 on Debian Squeeze. I ran `sensors-detect` and then `sensors`, but I only get my motherboard sensors (it8720-isa-0228). There are three temperature values there but I assume those are not for the CPU.

```
it8720-isa-0228
Adapter: ISA adapter
in0:         +1.36 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +4.08 V)
in1:         +1.50 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +4.08 V)
in2:         +3.38 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +4.08 V)
in3:         +2.93 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +4.08 V)
in4:         +3.07 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +4.08 V)
in5:         +4.08 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +4.08 V)
in6:         +4.08 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +4.08 V)
in7:         +2.93 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +4.08 V)
Vbat:        +3.01 V
fan1:       3375 RPM  (min =   10 RPM)
fan2:          0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan3:       1730 RPM  (min =   10 RPM)
fan5:          0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
temp1:       +27.0Â°C  (low  = +127.0Â°C, high = +127.0Â°C)  sensor = thermistor
temp2:       +53.0Â°C  (low  = +127.0Â°C, high = +127.0Â°C)  sensor = thermal diode
temp3:       +65.0Â°C  (low  = +127.0Â°C, high = +90.0Â°C)  sensor = thermal diode
cpu0_vid:   +0.000 V
```

Is there anything I am missing?

I also loaded the K8temp and K10temp modules and ran `sensor-detect` without any results.    I do see this message in dmesg:

```
hwmon-vid: Unknown VRM version of your x86 CPU
```

Comment: Related (cross-site): *[How do I get the CPU temperature?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/15832)*

Answer (score 5):

I had to do two things to monitor my [FX8350](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piledriver_(processor)#Desktop): Turn on IOMMU in my BIOS and load the `it87` module.

I have an [Asus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asus) board, and it has the IOMMU options in the BIOS under Advanced `-->` Northbridge, I believe.

`sudo modprobe it87` should take care of the rest. Of course, you'll want to add a line to `/etc/modules`, so `it87` will load on boot. If you run `sudo sensors-detect` it will offer to add the option to `/etc/modules` for you.

Comment: Turning on IOMMU in the BIOS worked for me (MSI motherboard with FX8300: *Overclocking settings* -> *CPU Features* -> *IOMMU*, changed "Disabled" to "64 MB" (the only other option)).